# Qt Setting A TabBar

Tags: c++, qt

I am making an application using the Qt Framework and I run into a problem:
I define a TabWidget like this

```
QTabWidget *armaTab = new QTabWidget();
armaTab->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
armaTab->setTabPosition(QTabWidget::North);
armaTab->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("armaTab"));
```

then I try to add a QTabBar Like This:

```
QTabBar *tabBar = new QTabBar();
tabBar->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
tabBar->setFont(*font);
tabBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("armaTabBar"));
armaTab->setTabBar(tabBar);
```

And I get this error:

```
error: 'void QTabWidget::setTabBar(QTabBar*)' is protected
error: within this context
```

May someone please explain where my mistake lies?

Comment: Unless you're subclassing QTabWidget you shouldn't be creating your own QTabBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that simply means that you must follow some attention to access the component: from docs:

> void QTabWidget::setTabBar ( QTabBar * tb ) [protected]
>
> Replaces the dialog's QTabBar heading with the tab bar tb. Note that this must be called before any tabs have been added, or the behavior is undefined.

I think you can simply subclass QTabWidget to get access to protected member(s)...